# Average Value for non-differentiable function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals, continuity, average

Surprisingly, I could find no answers for this on either YouTube or the internet. I'm looking for the average *rate of change* on the interval $[-1,3]$ of the function: $$f(t)=6t^2+\frac{4}{t^2}$$
Now, despite the function being non-differentiable at $0$, we can still easily take the derivative:
$$f'(t)=12t-\frac{8}{t^3}$$
And I can easily find the average value by hand:
$$ave_{f'}=\frac{1}{4}\int_{-1}^3 12t-\frac{8}{t^3} \,dt=\frac{6t^2+\frac{4}{t^2}\Big|_{-1}^3}{4}=\frac{100}{9}$$
However, I am afraid that this method is improper due to the discontinuity. If I put that same integral into either Desmos or Symbolab, it complains and says that the integral diverges. I can think of two alternate methods to solve:

1. $$\frac{1}{4}\left[\lim_{a\to0^-} \int_{-1}^a 12t-\frac{8}{t^3} \,dt+\lim_{a\to0^+}\int_{a}^3 12t-\frac{8}{t^3} \,dt\right]$$
2. Or, using the fact that the function is even (reflection over y-axis) means that the derivatives from $-1$ to $0$ and from $0$ to $1$ will cancel each other out, and we can simply take the average value from $1$ to $3$:
   $$ave_{f'}=\frac{1}{4}\left[0+\int_{1}^3 12t-\frac{8}{t^3} \,dt\right]=\frac{6t^2+\frac{4}{t^2}\Big|_{1}^3}{4}=\frac{100}{9}$$
   Which is the proper method to explain to my student? Thanks!

Comment: This average rate of change just doesn’t exist.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: Even if the average value does not exist, it may be $\pm ∞ $

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net If that's true, then what are my errors? Should I say that "even though we can calculate the integral by hand, the result is not valid due to the discontinuity at 0"? And how about my alternate method #2? Certainly the average rate of change exists from 1 to 3? And certainly the average rate of change from -1 to 1 is 0 due to symmetry, no?

Comment: @AlexR. The Cauchy Principle seems to match what I was trying to do with alternate method #1, right? Is that the explanation that I should go with?

Comment: @user3925803 You’re trying to compute the integral of a map that is not integrable.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net That's quite a vague response to multiple specific questions. I guess I'll just trust my instincts. No further comments necessary.

Comment: That is not vague at all! Just refer to what an integrable map over an interval is. Your $f$ is not integrable over $[-1,3]$ should you refer to Lebesgue or Riemann definition of integrability. As a consequence, the rate of change of $f$ over that interval is not defined.